# Navigation Bar disappearing while scrolling

Tags: xcode, navigationbar

I am using table view in my app. I manually created the table view with basic cells. I inserted a navigation bar on the top of the screen. When I scroll down, the navigation bar disappears. To make it reappear, I have to scroll back to the top of the screen. How do I ensure that the navigation abr is constantly there on the screen, while I am scrolling down.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways.

First way is to embed your view controller in Navigation controller instead of adding navigation bar directly to your view controller. Select your view controller and select **Editor->Embed in->Navigation controller**. It will add a navigation controller to the storyboard and will set up your view controller as its root controller.
This will work even if you use Tableview Controller (which won't let you add navigation bar manually in interface builder).
I would recommend you to use this way.

See screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydt7R.jpg

---

Second way is to add navigation bar directly to the controller and to check the hierarchy of the views: both table view and navigation bar should be on the same level and navigation bar should follow table view. Most likely your navigation bar was added as a subview of the table view.
Note that I  would not recommend you to follow this way, because you will have to manually add constraints, this method won't work with table view controller, plus you can run in some other problems.

See screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tGdX.jpg